# Fragment with ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

The mainactivity contains navigation drawer. When I click on the navigation drawer tabs, the respective fragment will be opened and in that fragment in Homefragment I want to add ViewPager.

I have added ViewPager in HomeFragment but it is not scrolling horizontally.

This is mainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private NavigationView navigationView;
private DrawerLayout drawer;
private View navHeader;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private FloatingActionButton fab;

public static int navItemIndex = 0;


private static final String TAG_HOME = "home";
private static final String TAG_PHOTOS = "photos";
private static final String TAG_MOVIES = "movies";
private static final String TAG_NOTIFICATIONS = "notifications";
private static final String TAG_SETTINGS = "settings";
public static String CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;

// toolbar titles respected to selected nav menu item
private String[] activityTitles;


private boolean shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress = true;
private Handler mHandler;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.app_bar_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mHandler = new Handler();

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    // load toolbar titles from string resources
    activityTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_item_activity_titles);

    // Navigation view header
    navHeader = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    // load nav menu header data
    loadNavHeader();

    // initializing navigation menu
    setUpNavigationView();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        navItemIndex = 0;
        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
        loadHomeFragment();
    }
}


private void loadNavHeader() {

    // showing dot next to notifications label
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(3).setActionView(R.layout.menu_dot);
}


private void loadHomeFragment() {
    // selecting appropriate nav menu item
    selectNavMenu();

    // set toolbar title
    setToolbarTitle();

    // if user select the current navigation menu again, don't do anything
    // just close the navigation drawer
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CURRENT_TAG) != null) {
        drawer.closeDrawers();

        // show or hide the fab button
        toggleFab();
        return;
    }


    Runnable mPendingRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // update the main content by replacing fragments
            Fragment fragment = getHomeFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                    android.R.anim.fade_out);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);
            fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }
    };


    if (mPendingRunnable != null) {
        mHandler.post(mPendingRunnable);
    }

    // show or hide the fab button
    toggleFab();


    drawer.closeDrawers();


    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

private Fragment getHomeFragment() {
    switch (navItemIndex) {
        case 0:

            HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
            return homeFragment;
        case 1:

            PhotosFragment photosFragment = new PhotosFragment();
            return photosFragment;
        case 2:

            MoviesFragment moviesFragment = new MoviesFragment();
            return moviesFragment;
        case 3:

            NotificationsFragment notificationsFragment = new NotificationsFragment();
            return notificationsFragment;

        case 4:

            SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
            return settingsFragment;
        default:
            return new HomeFragment();
    }
}

private void setToolbarTitle() {
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(activityTitles[navItemIndex]);
}

private void selectNavMenu() {
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(navItemIndex).setChecked(true);
}

private void setUpNavigationView() {

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {


        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {


            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.nav_home:
                    navItemIndex = 0;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_photos:
                    navItemIndex = 1;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_PHOTOS;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_movies:
                    navItemIndex = 2;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_MOVIES;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_service_message:
                    navItemIndex = 3;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_NOTIFICATIONS;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_settings:
                    navItemIndex = 4;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_SETTINGS;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_about_us:

                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutUsActivity.class));
                    drawer.closeDrawers();
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_privacy_policy:

                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PrivacyPolicyActivity.class));
                    drawer.closeDrawers();
                    return true;
                default:
                    navItemIndex = 0;
            }


            if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
                menuItem.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                menuItem.setChecked(true);
            }
            menuItem.setChecked(true);

            loadHomeFragment();

            return true;
        }
    });


    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {

            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };


    drawer.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);


    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        return;
    }


    if (shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress) {

        if (navItemIndex != 0) {
            navItemIndex = 0;
            CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
            loadHomeFragment();
            return;
        }
    }

    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    if (navItemIndex == 0) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    }


    if (navItemIndex == 3) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.notifications, menu);
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


private void toggleFab() {
    if (navItemIndex == 0)
        fab.show();
    else
        fab.hide();
}
}
```

This is HomeFragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

public HomeFragment() {

}

View view;
ViewPager viewPager;
PagerAdapter adapter;
String[] rank;
String[] country;
String[] population;
int[] flag;
public PageIndicator mIndicator;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    rank = new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" };

    country = new String[] { "China", "India", "United States",
            "Indonesia", "Brazil", "Pakistan", "Nigeria", "Bangladesh",
            "Russia", "Japan" };

    population = new String[] { "1,354,040,000", "1,210,193,422",
            "315,761,000", "237,641,326", "193,946,886", "182,912,000",
            "170,901,000", "152,518,015", "143,369,806", "127,360,000" };

    flag = new int[] { R.drawable.china, R.drawable.india,
            R.drawable.unitedstates, R.drawable.indonesia,
            R.drawable.brazil, R.drawable.pakistan, R.drawable.nigeria,
            R.drawable.bangladesh, R.drawable.russia, R.drawable.japan };

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mIndicator = (PageIndicator) view.findViewById(R.id.pagerIndicator);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);

    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity(), rank, country, population, flag);

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);

}
}
```

This is adapter-

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

```
Context context;
String[] rank;
String[] country;
String[] population;
int[] flag;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, String[] rank, String[] country,
                        String[] population, int[] flag) {
    this.context = context;
    this.rank = rank;
    this.country = country;
    this.population = population;
    this.flag = flag;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return rank.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {


    TextView txtrank;
    TextView txtcountry;
    TextView txtpopulation;
    ImageView imgflag;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container,
            false);


    txtrank = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rank);
    txtcountry = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country);
    txtpopulation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.population);


    txtrank.setText(rank[position]);
    txtcountry.setText(country[position]);
    txtpopulation.setText(population[position]);

    // Locate the ImageView in viewpager_item.xml
    imgflag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);
    // Capture position and set to the ImageView
    imgflag.setImageResource(flag[position]);

    // Add viewpager_item.xml to ViewPager
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    // Remove viewpager_item.xml from ViewPager
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

}
```

}

Comment: Rohan Please check this link https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4680